# Using sw-toolbox with Parse JS SDK for runtime caching / offline does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, parse-platform, service-worker

I have an AngularJS app, and it uses Parse as the backend. I've made it offline friendly by using service worker - it uses sw-precache for caching the static resources during build time, and also uses runtime caching for certain whitelisted URLs (such as the parse API backend), and some other URLs.

Even with this in place, the runtime caching does not take effect once the app goes offline - it still tries to reach the /config URL on my parse server. I've tried whitelisting the URL with this pattern, and it still does not cache the response.

My (Grunt generated) service worker snippet is

```
    // Runtime cache configuration, using the sw-toolbox library.
    toolbox
    .router
    .get(/^https:\/\/xxx\.xxx\.com/, toolbox.networkFirst, 
       {"networkTimeoutSeconds":10,
        "cache":
             {
              "origin":"https://xxx.xxx.com",
              "maxEntries":10,
              "name":"main-cache",
              "maxAgeSeconds":1800
             }
       });
```

According to the docs, this config will cache any request to the domain in the whitelisted URL. I've tried playing around with `maxAgeSeconds` and `maxEntries`, and still have not seen the client caching as many mentioned there.

The idea is to have a completely offline and working AngularJS + Parse.com application that works on page reloads (we already use a lot of IndexedDb, localstorage while offline). Now the application works as long as the page is not reloaded, but the minute that it is - it makes an API call to the /config URL and the page remains blank with a few console error messages.

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: combined with fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API   , the SW handler  for general fetchs  ( fetch.listener)  https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/custom-offline-page/  can proxy any REST endpoint that produces a parse.RESPONSE. If you have a parse customer query say, you can pair the string URL ( ie rest endpoint ) with the actual RESPONSE and store that in the SW.cache where the listener will proxy it. Review the SW example listener. Compile a list of the endpoints u want to include in the cache and i think the example shows how to load your reqs.

Comment: I've since then migrated to using workbox, and while I have included the URL that needs to be proxied, the service worker does not cache / respond from its cache for this URL. every other static resource is loaded successfully. I believe the URLs you suggested are the low level implementation bits that workbox already takes into consideration. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Re static urls in cache calls. They need to be valid urls. I valid protocols, valid domain n path